# ASP.NET + SQL questions

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am using ASP.NET + VS2010 + WebMatrix, and want it to be so that when a user signs up, he/she creates a new table with their email as the table name, and the columns "where" and "what", both text. I already have this code,

```
@{
    // Set the layout page and page title
    Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
    Page.Title = "Register an Account";

    // Initialize general page variables
    var email = "";
    var password = "";
    var confirmPassword = "";

    // Validation
    var isValid = true;
    var emailErrorMessage = "";
    var passwordErrorMessage = "";
    var confirmPasswordMessage = "";
    var accountCreationErrorMessage = "";
    // var captchaMessage = "";

    // If this is a POST request, validate and process data
    if (IsPost) {
        email = Request.Form["email"];
        password = Request.Form["password"];
        confirmPassword = Request.Form["confirmPassword"];

        // Validate the user's captcha answer
        // if (!ReCaptcha.Validate("PRIVATE_KEY")) {
        //     captchaMessage = "Captcha response was not correct";
        //     isValid = false;
        // }

        // Validate the user's email address
        if (email.IsEmpty()) {
            emailErrorMessage = "You must specify an email address.";
            isValid = false;
        }

        // Validate the user's password and password confirmation
        if (password.IsEmpty()) {
            passwordErrorMessage = "The password cannot be blank.";
            isValid = false;
        }

        if (password != confirmPassword) {
            confirmPasswordMessage = "The new password and confirmation password do not match.";
            isValid = false;
        }

        // If all information is valid, create a new account
        if (isValid) { 
            // Insert a new user into the database
            var db = Database.Open("StarterSite");

            // Check if user already exists
            var user = db.QuerySingle("SELECT Email FROM UserProfile WHERE LOWER(Email) = LOWER(@0)", email);
            if (user == null) {
                // Insert email into the profile table
                db.Execute("INSERT INTO UserProfile (Email) VALUES (@0)", email);

                // Create and associate a new entry in the membership database.
                // If successful, continue processing the request
                try {
                    bool requireEmailConfirmation = !WebMail.SmtpServer.IsEmpty();
                    var token = WebSecurity.CreateAccount(email, password, requireEmailConfirmation);
                    if (requireEmailConfirmation) {
                        var hostUrl = Request.Url.GetComponents(UriComponents.SchemeAndServer, UriFormat.Unescaped);
                        var confirmationUrl = hostUrl + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Account/Confirm?confirmationCode=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(token));

                        WebMail.Send(
                            to: email, 
                            subject: "Please confirm your account", 
                            body: "Your confirmation code is: " + token + ". Visit <a href=\"" + confirmationUrl + "\">" + confirmationUrl + "</a> to activate your account."
                        ); 
                    }

                    if (requireEmailConfirmation) {
                        // Thank the user for registering and let them know an email is on its way
                        Response.Redirect("~/Account/Thanks");
                    } else {
                        // Navigate back to the homepage and exit
                        WebSecurity.Login(email, password);
                        Response.Redirect("~/");
                    }
                } catch (System.Web.Security.MembershipCreateUserException e) {
                    isValid = false;
                    accountCreationErrorMessage = e.ToString();
                }
            } else {
                // User already exists
                isValid = false;
                accountCreationErrorMessage = "Email address is already in use.";
            }
        }    
    }
}

<p>
   Use the form below to create a new account. 
</p>

@* If at least one validation error exists, notify the user *@
@if (!isValid) {
   <p class="message error">
    @if (accountCreationErrorMessage.IsEmpty()) {
        @:Please correct the errors and try again.
    } else {
        @accountCreationErrorMessage
    }
   </p>
}

<form method="post" action="">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Sign-up Form</legend>
        <ol>
            <li class="email">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" title="Email address" value="@email" @if(!emailErrorMessage.IsEmpty()){<text>class="error-field"</text>} />
                @* Write any email validation errors to the page *@
                @if (!emailErrorMessage.IsEmpty()) {
                    <label for="email" class="validation-error">@emailErrorMessage</label>
                }
            </li>
            <li class="password">
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" title="Password" @if(!passwordErrorMessage.IsEmpty()){<text>class="error-field"</text>} />
                @* Write any password validation errors to the page *@
                @if (!passwordErrorMessage.IsEmpty()) {
                    <label for="password" class="validation-error">@passwordErrorMessage</label>
                }
            </li>
            <li class="confirm-password">
                <label for="confirmPassword">Confirm Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" title="Confirm password" @if(!confirmPasswordMessage.IsEmpty()){<text>class="error-field"</text>} />
                @* Write any password validation errors to the page *@
                @if (!confirmPasswordMessage.IsEmpty()) {
                    <label for="confirmPassword" class="validation-error">@confirmPasswordMessage</label>
                }
            </li>
            <li class="recaptcha">
                <div class="message info">
                    <p>To enable CAPTCHA verification, install the ASP.NET Web Helpers Library and uncomment ReCaptcha.GetHtml and replace 'PUBLIC_KEY'
                    with your public key.  At the top of this page, uncomment ReCaptcha.Validate and
                    replace 'PRIVATE_KEY' with your private key, and also uncomment the captchaMessage variable.</p>
                    <p>Register for reCAPTCHA keys at <a href="http://recaptcha.net">reCAPTCHA.net</a>.</p>
                </div>
                @*@ReCaptcha.GetHtml("PUBLIC_KEY", theme: "white")
                @if (!captchaMessage.IsEmpty()) {
                    <label class="validation-error">@captchaMessage</label>
                }*@
            </li>
        </ol>
        <p class="form-actions">
            <input type="submit" value="Register" title="Register" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

For the registration page that comes with it.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: what would be the code to create a new table with the users email as the name, and 2 columns, both text, called where and what. In the Database "usr"

Comment: email cannot be name of table: "Table names must follow the rules for identifiers" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx

Comment: I think you need to re-think how you are going about this. You don't go about creating new tables in a database for every user that signs up!

Comment: Agree with Shiv Kumar here - why do you think you would *want* to create a separate table for each user?

Answer (score 0):

```
            // Insert email into the profile table
            db.Execute("INSERT INTO UserProfile (Email) VALUES (@0)", email);

            // create the where/what table
            db.Execute("IF OBJECT_ID('" + user + "') IS NULL CREATE TABLE [" + user + "] ([where] nvarchar(max), what nvarchar(max))");
```

You may want to add some protection around the user variables to prevent SQL injection.

Note: `where` is a reserved keyword, so put square brackets around it. Put them around the email address as well for that matter.